# How to increase plotting intervall in ThingsBoard Dashboard

Tags: iot, thingsboard

I have successfully managed to install ThingsBoard on a Ubuntu 18.04. In my application I want to send large data packages from a few (<20) devices via MQTT. I also want to display the incoming data packets in real time.

For testing purposes I now play with the chart dashboard of ThingsBoard. Unfortunately I am not able to set the plotting interval on the dashboard to less than 1 second.

This is the current situation and I try to increase the speed of the plot:
[Dashboard GIF](https://giphy.com/gifs/fs6rozG1u6lqYTtVfz)

Are there any other settings that would meet my needs?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

change the "data aggregation function" to "none" and it will start displaying real-time, raw data.